# C++: hashtable - Why won't this compile?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, hashtable

I have the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <google/dense_hash_map>
#include <string.h>

using google::dense_hash_map;      // namespace where class lives by default
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::tr1::hash;  // or __gnu_cxx::hash, or maybe tr1::hash, depending on your OS

struct eqstr
{
  bool operator()(const char* s1, const char* s2) const
  {
    return (s1 == s2) || (s1 && s2 && strcmp(s1, s2) == 0);
  }
};

int main(void){
  dense_hash_map<const int, const char*, hash<const int>, eqstr> months;

  months.set_empty_key(0);
  months[1234] = "1234";

  cout << "1234:" << months[1234] << endl;
}
```

As you can see, I'm implementing a hash table using Google's sparsehash library.

I am using integers as the key and strings as the value.

But I keep getting the following compilation error that I can't get to the bottom of:

> make all  Building file: ../src/Main.cpp Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
>   g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Main.d"
>   -MT"src/Main.d" -o"src/Main.o" "../src/Main.cpp" In file included from
>   /usr/local/include/google/dense_hash_map:104:0,
>                    from ../src/Main.cpp:2:
>   /usr/local/include/google/sparsehash/densehashtable.h: In member
>   function ‘bool google::dense_hashtable::KeyInfo::equals(const key_type&,
>   const key_type&) const [with Value = std::pair, Key = int, HashFcn = std::tr1::hash, ExtractKey =
>   google::dense_hash_map,
>   eqstr>::SelectKey, SetKey = google::dense_hash_map, eqstr>::SetKey, EqualKey = eqstr, Alloc =
>   google::libc_allocator_with_realloc
>
> > , key_type = int]’:
> >     /usr/local/include/google/sparsehash/densehashtable.h:1306:32:
> >     instantiated from ‘bool google::dense_hashtable::equals(const key_type&, const
> >     key_type&) const [with Value = std::pair, Key
> >     = int, HashFcn = std::tr1::hash, ExtractKey =
> >     google::dense_hash_map,
> >     eqstr>::SelectKey, SetKey = google::dense_hash_map, eqstr>::SetKey, EqualKey = eqstr, Alloc =
> >     google::libc_allocator_with_realloc
> >     , key_type = int]’
> >     /usr/local/include/google/sparsehash/densehashtable.h:514:5:
> >     instantiated from ‘void google::dense_hashtable::set_empty_key(google::dense_hashtable::const_reference) [with Value =
> >     std::pair, Key = int, HashFcn =
> >     std::tr1::hash, ExtractKey = google::dense_hash_map, eqstr>::SelectKey, SetKey =
> >     google::dense_hash_map,
> >     eqstr>::SetKey, EqualKey = eqstr, Alloc =
> >     google::libc_allocator_with_realloc
> >     , google::dense_hashtable::const_reference = const std::pair&]’ /usr/local/include/google/dense_hash_map:298:5:
> >     instantiated from ‘void google::dense_hash_map::set_empty_key(google::dense_hash_map::key_type&) [with Key = int, T = const
> >     char*, HashFcn = std::tr1::hash, EqualKey = eqstr, Alloc =
> >     google::libc_allocator_with_realloc
> >     , google::dense_hash_map::key_type
> >     = int]’ ../src/Main.cpp:21:25:   instantiated from here
> >     /usr/local/include/google/sparsehash/densehashtable.h:1293:39: error:
> >     invalid conversion from ‘google::dense_hashtable, int, std::tr1::hash, google::dense_hash_map, eqstr,
> >     google::libc_allocator_with_realloc
> >
> > > ::SelectKey, eqstr,
> > >       google::libc_allocator_with_realloc
> > >       , google::dense_hash_map,
> > >       eqstr, google::libc_allocator_with_realloc > >::SetKey, eqstr,
> > >       google::libc_allocator_with_realloc
> > >       , eqstr, google::libc_allocator_with_realloc > >::key_type’ to ‘const char*’
> > >       /usr/local/include/google/sparsehash/densehashtable.h:1293:39: error: 
> > >       initializing argument 1 of ‘bool eqstr::operator()(const char*, const
> > >       char*) const’
> > >       /usr/local/include/google/sparsehash/densehashtable.h:1293:39: error:
> > >       invalid conversion from ‘google::dense_hashtable, int, std::tr1::hash, google::dense_hash_map, eqstr,
> > >       google::libc_allocator_with_realloc
> > >       ::SelectKey, eqstr,
> > >       google::libc_allocator_with_realloc
> > >       , google::dense_hash_map,
> > >       eqstr, google::libc_allocator_with_realloc > >::SetKey, eqstr,
> > >       google::libc_allocator_with_realloc
> > >       , eqstr, google::libc_allocator_with_realloc > >::key_type’ to ‘const char*’
> > >       /usr/local/include/google/sparsehash/densehashtable.h:1293:39: error: 
> > >       initializing argument 2 of ‘bool eqstr::operator()(const char*, const
> > >       char*) const’ make: *** [src/Main.o] Error 1

It seems very verbose and I can't make any sense of it.

I should add that when I use strings as the key and integers as the value, it works fine:

```
dense_hash_map<const char*, int, hash<const char*>, eqstr> months;
...
months["february"] = 2;   //works fine
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Many thanks in advance,

---

Edit: got it working now!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <google/dense_hash_map>
#include <string.h>

using google::dense_hash_map;      // namespace where class lives by default
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::tr1::hash;  // or __gnu_cxx::hash, or maybe tr1::hash, depending on your OS

struct eqstr
{
  bool operator()(int s1, int s2) const
  {
    return (s1 == s2); //|| (s1 && s2 && strcmp(s1, s2) == 0);
  }
};

int main(void){
  dense_hash_map<int, const char*, hash<int>, eqstr> months;

  months.set_empty_key(0);
  months[1234] = "1234";

  cout << "1234:" << months[1234] << endl;
}
```

Totally forgot about editing the eqstr struct to accomodate the new data types... *bangs head off desk*

Comment: The complaint is that eqstr should expect the key type, and the key type is not const char*.  I don't know enough about the type to say what the key type is (unsigned int?) based on your declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out by yourself, it works if you use `const char*` as key. The hashmap indeed requires a hashing function to hash the keys to buckets and a comparison function to establish a strict weak ordering within the buckets - all this for the key type, the value type is just stored! So to make it work, define a comparison function for `int` (I don't know whether `const int` is fine with `google::dense_hash_map`, I think it should be `int`).

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out the hard way... Thanks so much for your answer!